# Existe uma maneira de simplificar a criação de vários botões com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Pretendo criar 4 botões diferentes e quero saber se consigo simplificar o meu código para caso eu queira aumentar ou diminuir a quantidade de botões.

Objetivo: clicar no botão e alterar a classe do elemento body e uma imagem de exibição de acordo com o botão específico, cada botão deve mudar para uma classe e imagem diferente de outro botão.

```
<!-- html -->
<div id="tema">            
   <img id="img-theme" src="./images-geometric/blue.png" alt="Temas">
   <div id="images-theme">
     <span>Temas</span>
       <img id="themePurple" src="./images-geometric/purple.png" alt="Temas">
       <img id="themeYellow" src="./images-geometric/yellow.png" alt="Temas">
       <img id="themeBlue" src="./images-geometric/blue.png" alt="Temas">
       <img id="themeGreen" src="./images-geometric/green.png" alt="Temas">
   </div>
</div>
```

```
//javascript
let imgTheme = document.querySelector('#img-theme')

let themePurple = document.querySelector('#themePurple').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.removeAttribute('class')
    document.body.classList.toggle('purple')
    imgTheme.setAttribute('src', './images-geometric/purple.png')
})

let themeYellow = document.querySelector('#themeYellow').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.removeAttribute('class')
    document.body.classList.toggle('yellow')
    imgTheme.setAttribute('src', './images-geometric/yellow.png')
})

let themeBlue = document.querySelector('#themeBlue').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.removeAttribute('class')
    document.body.classList.toggle('blue')
    imgTheme.setAttribute('src', './images-geometric/blue.png')
})

let themeGreen = document.querySelector('#themeGreen').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.removeAttribute('class')
    document.body.classList.toggle('green')
    imgTheme.setAttribute('src', './images-geometric/green.png')
})
```

Comment: Qual é o impeditivo?

Comment: O código funciona, eu gostaria de saber se consigo simplifica-lo

Comment: Usando um array e loop, salva as informações necessárias em uma lista e roda o bloco de código que cria os botões e adiciona o evento dentro de um `for`

Answer (score 1):

Em programação orientada a objetos, existe um padrão de projeto chamado factory, que resolve seu problema. A ideia é delegar a criação das instâncias a um objeto (a *factory*, ou fábrica).

Por simplicidade, eu não vou usar classes; vou só fazer funções para isso.

O código tem alguns pressupostos, como o de que as imagens preexistem e estão na pasta `./images-geometric/`, e têm o nome `cor_respectiva.png`, mas tudo pode ser adaptados facilmente.

Agora, para você adicionar botões, nem precisa mais mexer no HTML. É só adicionar, no Javascript, uma linha `let themeCorNova = themeOptionFactoryCreate("cor-nova", imgsContainer)` e garantir que o ícone `cor-nova.png` esteja na pasta `./images-geometric`.

```html
<!-- html -->
<div id="tema">            
   <img id="img-theme" src="./images-geometric/blue.png" alt="Temas">
   <div id="images-theme">
     <span>Temas</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

```js
//arquivo js
const imgsContainer = document.querySelector('#images-theme') 

let themePurple = themeOptionFactoryCreate("purple", imgsContainer)
let themeYellow = themeOptionFactoryCreate("yellow", imgsContainer)
let themeBlue = themeOptionFactoryCreate("blue", imgsContainer)
let themeGreen = themeOptionFactoryCreate("green", imgsContainer)

function themeOptionFactoryCreate(colorName, container) {
    const button = createOptionButton(colorName, container)
    createEventListener(button, colorName)
    return button
}

function createOptionButton(colorName, container) {
    const themeName = "theme" + colorName[0].toUpperCase() + colorName.slice(1).toLowerCase()
    const themeImgElement = document.createElement("img")
    themeImgElement.setAttribute("id", themeName)
    themeImgElement.setAttribute("src", `./images-geometric/${colorName}.png`)
    themeImgElement.setAttribute("alt", "Temas")
    container.appendChild(themeImgElement)
    return themeImgElement
}

function createEventListener(button, colorName, container) {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.body.removeAttribute('class')
        document.body.classList.toggle(colorName)
        document.querySelector('#img-theme').setAttribute('src', `./images-geometric/${colorName}.png`)
    })
}
```